# Reorder items after mouse release

Tags: java, swing

I am not sure what is wrong, so I will attempt to explain it, and you can test it in the following example:
The Project (3 MB): http://ryannaddy.com/downloads/dist.zip

1. Un-Zip and run the jar file
2. Open 2 image files within the application
3. On the right hand side is a list of all the open images, you can drag and drop the layers to eventually order z-order of the main picture.
4. If you drag the top layer below the bottom layer it gets moved back to the top (Should be moved below the bottom layer)
5. If you drag the top layer down a few pixels it will move the top layer below the bottom layer.
6. If you drag the bottom layer down it moves it above the top layer (Should be kept on the bottom)

In the end, I would like to drag those labels to any spot and there is where it will place the label.

Code block that gets executed after the mouse is released to organize the labels:

```
public void lblMouseReleased(MouseEvent evt){
    if(dragging){
        int componentCount = layers.getComponentCount() - 1;
        LayerItem[] comps = new LayerItem[componentCount];

        FocusTraversalPolicy focus = layers.getFocusTraversalPolicy();

        Component comp = focus.getFirstComponent(layers);
        for(int i = 0; i < componentCount; i++){
            Component newComp = focus.getComponentAfter(layers, comp);
            comp = newComp;
            comps[i] = (LayerItem)newComp;
            System.out.println(comps[i].layerID);
        }
        Layers.rebuild(layers, comps);
    }
    dragging = false;
}
```

Code for **Layers.rebuild**:

```
public static void rebuild(JPanel layers, Component[] list){
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        layers.remove(list[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        list[i].setBounds(0, i * 50 + 30, 198, 50);
        layers.add(list[i]);
    }
    layers.revalidate();
    layers.repaint();
}
```

This should be all the relevant code to the problem, let me know if you need more.

Comment: Less is more; please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: That is odd, when I strip everything down to make sscce code, and run a test my code works exactly how I want it! I guess there must be something else wrong in the main code that I need to look into.

Comment: @RyanNaddy nobody wants to investigate 3mb of your code trying to figure out what's wrong. At least not for free. That's why we ask SSCCE. If your SSCCE works properly compare it with your code to find the difference.

Comment: It was actually a fully compiled program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I it was because I wasn't getting all the items needed in the panel. The first item in my panel is a header with focus set to false, since it isn't apart of the grouping, so I was telling my code to only order items 1+ when it should have been 0+