# Drag-and-drop to order items in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a list of items to display in Swing. For simplicity, imagine that each item consists of only a name. I want the user to be able to order these items by dragging and dropping them above/below each other. What's the best way to achieve this?

Alternatively, could this perhaps be accomplished in using a JList, with an "up" and "down" button that would move the selected item up/down in the list. This would require updating the graphical display instantly on each click (I don't know how to do this), and saving the new order by getting the items in the list in their current order (which I also don't know how to do).

Or might a drag-and-drop solution be more feasible?

Comment: not sure if this can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692357/reorder-items-after-mouse-release

Comment: Have you read any of the tutorials or JavaDocs for Swing?  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html  Maybe you could list the things you've tried so far and what worked or didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd probably be easier to implement this with the `JList` solution you mention, so I'll give you some pointers on that (I'm not very experienced with D&D).

Basically, you want to have three components: a `JList` and two (one up, one down) `JButton`s. You'll also probably want a custom list model. If you're unfamiliar with models or list models, check out [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html). Otherwise, read on.

In the list model class (e.g., `ReorderableListModel`), go ahead and define two methods: `public void moveUp(int index)` and `public void moveDown(int index)`.

The code for `moveUp` is as follows:

```
if (index > 0) { // error checking
    // Swap the given index with the previous index.
    // (where `list` is the name of your list variable)
    Collections.swap(list, index, index - 1);
}
// Finally, notify the `JList` that the list structure has changed.
fireContentsChanged(this, index - 1, index);
```

`moveDown` is similar:

```
if (index < getSize() - 1) {
    Collections.swap(list, index, index + 1);
}
fireContentsChanged(this, index, index + 1);
```

Now, we need to implement the action listeners for the buttons. For the up button, go try this listener code:

```
// First, move the item up in the list.
listModel.moveUp(list.getSelectedIndex());

// Now, set the selection index to keep the same item selected.
//
// If you use the default list selection interval, setting the index to -1
// will do nothing (so it's okay, we don't need error checking here).
list.setSelectedIndex(list.getSelectedIndex() - 1);
```

Add a similar "move down" method and you're done!

With respect to "updating the graphical display instantly on each click," that's what the `fireContentsChanged` method in the model class does. `JList` will do the updating for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a functionality hard to achieve using just swing. Have you heard about JavaFX? It is a great graphic framework to work with if you want to achieve more dynamic functionality in desktop applications, take a look to this article: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html

Here you will be able to find links with more information, as well as some examples. Best regards.

Comment: In his blog, Narayan details a solution for [using drag and drop to order items using a JavaFX ListView](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2012/05/06/javafx-drag-and-drop-cell-in-listview/).